# How can I detect Android phones and Android tablets differently using the user agent header?

Tags: php, android, header, user-agent

For my site I need to be able to tell the difference between when an Android tablet visits  and when an Android phone visits. It needs to be detected before the page is sent to the user so using JavaScript to check the screen res isn't an option.

At the moment I use this to detect an android device: 
stripos($ua, 'android')

Is there anything unique thar a tablet has in it's user agent?

Comment: If you code your page using semantic HTML and CSS, then you should not need to detect device type before you send the page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] then case-insensitive eregi functions to look for the following, which assumes the browser developer followed Android's guidelines on user agent specification:

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (eregi('Android', $ua) && eregi('Mobile', $ua)) $platform = "Android Phone";
elseif (eregi('Android', $ua) && !eregi('Mobile', $ua)) $platform = "Android Tablet";
```

It's not foolproof but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) project. It should be able to help you out not only in Android Phone and Android Tablet scenario but also other devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick Kershner, your code only works for the family of Apple products. Each Apple device sends its own UA, but that's not the case with Android devices. In fact, the author of this post needs to know whether the Android device is a tablet or a phone without using Javascript. The code submitted by user user336828 is a great workaround for this, although not 100% reliable: some clone/white-label/low quality devices may send exactly the same UA string from both tablets and phones, but I think this should work with most known brand's devices. I just tested that code on both an Android phone and a tablet and it's working.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') ||   strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android')){ 
    //do something...
}
```

Worked for me