# PHP: detect name of android device?

Tags: php, user-agent

I want to know how I can detect the Android device the visitor uses in PHP, for eg. Galaxy S. While browsing facebook from my phone, I saw:
"Install Facebook on your Galaxy S and browse faster"

So I viewed phpinfo(); located on my server from the same browser I used while browsing facebook and searched for "galaxy" text and got no matches. So how come it detected my device name? And how can I detect it on my PHP script?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump(getallheaders());`

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952452/how-can-i-detect-android-phones-and-android-tablets-differently-using-the-user-a

Comment: my server doesnt have getallheaders() enabled

Comment: Tried:

        function getallheaders() 
        { 
               $headers = ''; 
           foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) 
           { 
               if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') 
               { 
                   $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value; 
               } 
           } 
           return $headers; 
        } 
    getallheaders();

And then loaded it in browser and did a "find in page" for galaxy & got no matches

Comment: You wont find the text `galaxy`, you will find the model number, for example my samsung galaxy s4 mini sends `GT-19195` in the user agent.

Comment: It was "Galaxy S" when I used Opera Mobile browser.

Comment: and i couldnt even find the model no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found something like this in here :- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=205417

Check whether it's useful for you not.

```
<?php
/* detect mobile device*/
$ismobile = 0;
$container = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
// A list of mobile devices 
$useragents = array ( 
'Blazer' ,
'Palm' ,
'Handspring' ,
'Nokia' ,
'Kyocera',
'Samsung' ,
'Motorola' ,
'Smartphone', 
'Windows CE' ,
'Blackberry' ,
'WAP' ,
'SonyEricsson',
'PlayStation Portable', 
'LG', 
'MMP',
'OPWV',
'Symbian',
'EPOC',
); 

foreach ( $useragents as $useragents ) { 
 if(strstr($container,$useragents)) {
   $ismobile = 1;
 }
}
if ( $ismobile == 1 ) {
echo "<p>mobile device</p>";
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
?>
```

Some more stuffs here in here :- http://mobiledetect.net/

And some more :- http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Cheers!

Comment: it simply echoes $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']? and i stated in my question: So I viewed phpinfo(); located on my server from the same browser I used while browsing facebook and searched for "galaxy" text and got no matches.

Comment: I see. Check the links I've posted in the question. Might helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the superglobal `$_SERVER`.

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$info = get_browser($useragent);
```

For further information about the result of `get_browser` see the doku here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php
Most important for your purpous I guess would be `$info->platform`.

Comment: It will be very unlikely to retrieve a SPECIFIC device name from this.

Comment: My question contained: So I viewed phpinfo(); located on my server from the same browser I used while browsing facebook and searched for "galaxy" text and got no matches.

Comment: phpinfo(); Won't help you at all since it does not contain any information about the clinet side of things! It only contains information about your php environment as configuerd in the php.ini

Comment: phpinfo(); at the end contains client side vars like all $_SERVER directives.