# how to extract on mobile device name from php user agent?

Tags: php, user-agent

I am writing code that saves device details of the user. But when I am using PHP user agent it returns whole string of information. How do I extract only device name, for exmaple only model name like iPhone 6, Samsung Galaxy a5 etc?

I have tried some regex but that would be long code and I can't cover every single device.

I am getting

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1
```

I want only `iPhone OS 10_3_1`

Comment: please edit your post to show us the relevant bit of PHP which you use to get the user agent string and also show RegExp which you tried but which are not good enough because you specify the model manually. Please also don't start every word with a capital letter, such text is difficult to follow. This time, I've edit those for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many different ways a User Agent can be written it's hard to extract the information through just regex or simple logic. A better way would be to search for a list of given devices that you know can occur, such as from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25265306/10400050), however that might make it hard to extract the version information.

Instead I'd recommend using a third party library such as [device-detector](https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector) and use something in the following:

```
use DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector;

// Fetch the user agent
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

// Create an instance of DeviceDetector
$dd = new DeviceDetector($userAgent);

// Extract any information you want
$osInfo = $dd->getOs();
$device = $dd->getDeviceName();
$brand = $dd->getBrandName();
$model = $dd->getModel();
```

Comment: You will not get `$model` name in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Here your code.

```
$str = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1";

$pos1 = strpos($str, '(')+1;
$pos2 = strpos($str, ')')-$pos1;
$part = substr($str, $pos1, $pos2);
$parts = explode(" ", $part);
echo $parts[2].' '.$parts[3].' '.$parts[4];
```

Comment: there is so many possible user agent string. for those case your code will not work